# Reading the data in a contract using Json-rpc

Tags: json-rpc, bytecode

With access to the contract abi, how can the data from a contract be read?
You can get the byte code with [eth_getCode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getcode) but I don't understand how that can be converted to a readable form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found two methods for doing this:

- The data in a contract can be iterated through using [eth_getstorageat](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getstorageat) at 0x0, 0x1 etc. You can use the abi to find which variables are stored at each index.
- Public variables are automatically assigned a getter function. This can be called with [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) to return the value stored in that variable.